# In-place swap using tuple assigment statement

Tags: go, assignment-operator

*In-place swap* is a technique, which is used to swap a content of two distinct variables without any temporary storage variable.

GoLang Spec mentions: *A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued operation to a list of variables.*

---

Below code performs swap operation without using temporary variable(as per syntax):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a, b := 1, 2
    swapActual(&a, &b)
    fmt.Println(a, b)
    a, b = 1, 2
    swapCopy(a, b)
}

func swapActual(a, b *int) {
    *a, *b = *b, *a
}

func swapCopy(a, b int) {
    a, b = b, a
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

---

What is the mechanics behind evaluation of tuple assignment statement `*a, *b = *b, *a`? Does this evaluation involve temporary storage, implicitly?

Comment: "What is the mechanics behind evaluation of tuple assignment statement *a, *b = *b, *a? Does this evaluation involve temporary storage, implicitly?" This is implementation dependent. Nothing to see here, nothing to know here.

Comment: @Volker how tuple assignment swap values, without temporary variable?

Comment: This is entierly dependent on the compiler and hardware. Some hardware allows to do this on the hardware level or by using a CPU register which formally isn't a _variable_. There really is nothing to see or understand here.

Answer (score 0):

The line `*a, *b = *b, *a` in the `swap` function swaps the values of `a` and `b` without using a temporary variable.

This evaluation involves the use of pointers in Go. When `swap` is called, it receives the memory addresses (pointers) of `a` and `b`. The line `*a, *b = *b, *a` dereferences these pointers, meaning it retrieves the values stored at the memory addresses pointed to by `a` and `b`.

Here's a step-by-step breakdown:

1. `*a` retrieves the value stored at the memory address pointed to by `a`.
2. `*b` retrieves the value stored at the memory address pointed to by `b`.
3. `*a, *b = *b, *a` assigns the value of `*b` to `*a` and the value of `*a` to `*b`.

This evaluation doesn't involve temporary storage within the context of the user's code. It directly exchanges the values at the memory locations pointed to by `a` and `b`, effectively swapping their contents.

Comment: I don't get this point: *assigns the value of `*b` to `*a` and the value of `*a` to `*b`*

Comment: The exact mechanism depends on the compiler implementation. A simple compiler would likely evaluate on the system stack, as in push from a, push from b, pop to a, pop to b. More sophisticated compilers would likely use registers, or analyse the code to determine the original assignments are never used, and initialise the variables with the final values (omitting the swap statement entirely).